# Loop in C. The first loop in the program doesn't work and is infinite

Tags: c, loops, cs50

i don't understand why the first loop does not work. It is an infinite loop even if the owed float that is filled in is in fact bigger than 0. Why doesn't the loop work?

```
#import <cs50.h> 
#import <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float owed = -1 ;

    while (owed < 0) 
    {
        printf("O hai! How much change is owed?\n") ;
        float owed = GetFloat() ;
        owed = owed * 100 ;
    }

    int coins = 0 ;

    while (owed >= 25)
    {
        owed = owed - 25 ;
        coins = coins + 1 ;
    }

    while (owed >= 10)
    {
        owed = owed - 10 ;
        coins = coins + 1 ;
    }

    while (owed >= 5)
    {
        owed = owed - 5 ;
        coins = coins + 1 ;
    }

    while (owed >= 1) 
    {
        owed = owed - 1 ;
        coins = coins + 1 ;
    }

    printf("%i\n", coins) ;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `GetFloat() `?

Answer (score 5):

You need to change

```
float owed = GetFloat() ;
```

to

```
owed = GetFloat() ;
```

As you have two `owed` with different scopes. (you are not changing the outer one!)

**EDIT**

PS:
You can change the coude:

```
while (owed >= 25)
{
    owed = owed - 25 ;
    coins = coins + 1 ;
}
```

to

```
int new_coins = ((int)owed)/25;
coins += new_coins;
owed = owed - 25.0f * new_coins;
```

Comment: How could I change the outer owed while also making sure that a negative value cannot be implemented?

Comment: Just do the correction above. You can even move the multiplication outside the loop. Note -ve * +ve = -ve

Comment: thanks for your help, I figured the rest out. The code works now :)

Comment: @M.Schalkers - If you are happy accept an answer (Thomas below as he needs the reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two scope here. The main function scope and inside your first loop block scope. When you alter your declared variable inside the loop block, you don't alter the variable of your main function.

Your condition `while (owed < 0)` will never be true because your variable `owed` in main function scope will never change.

You need to not declare a new variable in the loop but use the variable declared in the main function, so you need to remove the `float` :

```
while (owed < 0) 
{
    printf("O hai! How much change is owed?\n") ;
    owed = GetFloat() ;
    owed = owed * 100 ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was thinking the problem could be related to that. But if I get rid of the first definition of owed than in the rest of my code (which is also outside the loop) owed is no longer defined. Is there any way in which I can make such a loop and then still be able to use the given float outside this loop?